# What is the best way make a copy of a blobstore entity on app engine in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

Here is our simple usecase:  user2 wants to copy user1's document into his or her own repository within our application.  Should be simple, right?  All we need to do is create a second identical blob in the blobstore with the key returned that we can associate with user2. We must be missing something here.  It appears that app engine blob store's primary function is to handle blobs uploaded from and downloaded to a browser, and a simple copy operation initiated server-side is not so simple.

The obvious solution seemed to be using the the experimental file api in java, but no love.  It works, until you get up in file size beyond a MB or so, then it fails, somewhat unpredictably.  Reading it all into the server layer also seems silly, when we just need to make a copy in the storage layer. In addition, the odds of us getting an experimental feature through into our production environment is slim, although non-zero.

Some information about our environment: the app is written in Java and we're using the blobstore, not cloud storage and are committed to it for now.  We're a small departmental team and would like to make the case that app engine is a great platform to use, but this one has us stumped.  S3 makes this blindingly simple, are we missing something really stupid here?

Comment: Since blobs cannot be modified, why make the copy at all? Just have another reference to the same blob for user2. If users are allowed to delete the contents of the blob, check the reference counter before really deleting it from the blobstore.

Comment: We thought about that but scrapped pretty fast because users can delete. Given the elegance of a single blob and the pain of copying, this is worth another look. What would be the best way to model this? A cross-reference entity to track whether a blob has more than one reference - create an entry in the cross reference entity when a blob is 'copied' and add/subtract a counter or id every time it's 'copied' or 'deleted' until there is only one reference.  We've had our challenges with counters and the data-store, so actually deleting when it's just the one last reference is a little scary.

Comment: After some debate, we've decided to go with a variant of Kalle's suggestion.  Answer below in case it will help others.  Also, in hindsight we thought we had a code implementation question, but it turned out to be an architectural question perhaps better suited for programers stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up scrapping the idea of making a programatic copy of the blob with the file api and going with a reference as Kalle suggested in his comment, and created a new xref entity that stores information about the copy and the original.  When an image or file is deleted, we check the xfef entity for references and delete the ones that point to that image/file (ie created if the deleted image/file was copied from another one). If we don't find any xrefs at all, we delete the blob itself. We didn't like the privacy/compliance implications of leaving orphaned blobs laying around, and even though storage is cheap every $$$ helps.  We also liked the idea of keeping a clean house so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: I will launch a Google Compute Engine instance and use the command gsutil to do the copy.

And then shutdown the instance when it's done. This is the fastest way to do the copy to my knowledge

[gsutil documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)

**Solution 2**: But I will personally choose to use a counter as said in the comments, because the point that you said is scary will be the same problem with the copy.
So just use counters with strong unit testing on those for example that will be less scary.

An idea to make it less scary is when you reach 0 for your counter you don't delete the blob right away but do a job to do this later on. By using [Scheduled task](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) in Google App Engine. And delete the file and your actual record of it a month later for example.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comment, keep one blob and pass the key around. But you really never need to delete. It is good practice to keep the blob for archive purposes. So how would `delete` actually work? In your datastore model, have a boolean delete field. You don't remove the blob key from an entity upon deletion. But rather, you mark the boolean field as `true`. This way, your product has a record of every user who has ever owned a file. But the user does not need to ever know.